# Predicting next destination. What type of classification it is?

Tags: machine-learning, probability, data-science, multiclass-classification

I have a very different machine learning problem. Or atleast I am facing such problem for 1st time.
It would be really great if u can guide me to solve it.

I have 3 data sets as follow:

hotel        star_rating        
  1        3
2            2

user    home_continent  gender
1                  2                                      female
2                   3                         female
3                    1                       male

user    hotel
1                            39
1         44
2         63

I need to find which hotel a user will visit next.
To me it does not look like normal classification or regression problem. Total 66 hotel and 4400 users
Can you please guide me.
Thanks

Comment: For each user you predict for each hotel the probability that that's the hotel the user picks next. Looks like a regression problem to me.

Comment: This is not a programming question and should be asked at http://stats.stackexchange.com

Comment: I am facing a similar challenge on a similar problem. Could you let  me know if you were able to solve it and  finally what method did you use to solve it
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It is a ranking problem (which, in many cases can be solved applying classification techniques).

Have a look to the documentation from [this Kaggle competition](https://www.kaggle.com/c/expedia-hotel-recommendations). It essentially poses the same kind of problem you are trying to solve.